# Stripe on-session payments require always authentication

Tags: stripe-payments

I am working with the Stripe API and I cannot find enough documentation regarding the on_session scenario.

I am saving the card after the first payment and setting the 'setup_future_usage' to 'on_session' because the customer is going to be always present in the checkout flow. However, this triggers authentication every time I try to pay something with the credit card number (4000002500003155). This type of credit card is intended to show only once the authentication process and to use the saved card for the subsequent off-session payment.

Answer (score 0):

It's still totally possible that the issuing bank will require that you authenticate the future on-session payments.  I don't think there's a test card to test the specific case you're trying to test though: https://stripe.com/docs/testing#regulatory-cards

Comment: Yes, I am aware that the issuing bank can require authentication for the future on-session payments. However, since this is in test mode this should not happen. So, in most cases the saved card with set_future_usage set to on-session should not require authentication for subsequent purchases after the initial purchase, is that correct? I cannot find anything regarding this scenario in stripe docs.

Comment: That's fair.  In this case that test card isn't meant to be used with `on-session` so it's probably seeing another `on-session` charge as something that needs authenticating.

Comment: Does this mean that any on_session payment regardless of the card being saved or not requires authentication?

Comment: No, it means that you're using the test card in a way it wasn't meant to be used.  Arguably this is a bug, so it's probably worth writing into Support to let them know: https://support.stripe.com/contact/email